# Which files are considered in the config resource-reload-check-secs?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, virtual-directory

I noticed that I need to use the [resource-reload-check-secs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13712/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP599) configuration in `weblogic.xml` to make the files in my Virtual Directory reloadable. The documentation says:

> The  element is used to perform metadata
>   caching for cached resources that are found in the resource path in
>   the Web application scope. This parameter identifies how often
>   WebLogic Server checks whether a resource has been modified and if so,
>   it reloads it.
>
> The value -1 means never reload. This is the default value in a
>   production environment.
>
> The value 0 means always reload.
>
> The value 1 means reload every second. This is the default value in a
>   development environment.

But what is considered a **resource path** for Weblogic? This will impact in my JavaScript and images files of the application?

Comment: Do any of these resources help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357473/unable-to-access-xml-file-from-virtual-directory-after-editing-the-file http://i-like-trains.blogspot.com/2008/01/weblogic-9-and-enabling-static-file.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457984/http-caching-headers-settings-weblogic

Comment: @castling The weblogic FileServlet seems interesting, I will take a look at it later.